# How would I delimit a string by multiple delimiters in bash

Tags: bash

How would I delimit a string by multiple characters in bash.
I want to get the first IP address.

```
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

I would do this

```
echo "inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0" | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d':' -f1
```

but I would like to combine the last two commands into one command.

I would like to get

`127.0.0.1`

Comment: edit your Q to include the required output from your sample input. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`, set the field delimiter as one or more space/tab or `:`, and get the third field:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]:]+' '{print $3}'
```

Note that, this would get the mentioned field delimiter separated third field, which may or may not be a valid IP address; from your attempt with `cut`, i am assuming the input is consistent.

**Example:**

```
% awk -F '[[:blank:]:]+' '{print $3}'  <<<'inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0'
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks that was it! I couldn't figure out what white spaces were and now I know it's [:blank:]

Comment: Note that this works with GNU awk, now all other awks. For other awks you could, for example: `awk '{sub(/^[^:]+:/,""); print $1}'` or replace the other delimiters with the one first: `awk '{gsub(/:/," "); print $3}'`.

Answer (score 2):

Set IFS to the delimiters:

```
echo inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 | 
   { IFS=': ' read i a ip m e; echo $ip; }
```

This will set the variable `i` to the string `inet`, `a` <- `addr`, `ip` <- `127.0.0.1`, `m` <- `Mask`, and `e` <- `255.0.0.0`.  Note that (in many shells) the variables are scoped and will lose their value outside of the braces.  There are techniques available to give them global scope in shells which sensibly restrict their scope, such as:

```
IFS=': ' read i a ip m e << EOF
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
EOF
echo $ip
```